# Display an integer in a view

Tags: f#-giraffe

I am new to Giraffe and having difficulties displaying an integer. My model is

```
type Person =
    {
        FirstName   : string
        LastName    : string
        Age         : int
    }
```

And my view is:

```
let index2 (model : Person) =
    [
        partial()
        p [] [
            encodedText model.FirstName
            br []
            encodedText model.LastName
            br []
            int model.Age
        ]
    ] |> layout
```

The error message returned is "All elements of a list must be of the same type. So how do I display the age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite familiar with Giraffe (rather Fable), so I do not know what to install and set to reproduce it.

Nevertheless, looking at `p [] [ ... ]`, it is clear that the function requires a list as a second parameter and therefore all the elements there should be of the same type.

Let's look inside. As per [GiraffeViewEngine.fs](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/src/Giraffe/GiraffeViewEngine.fs), `encodedText` returns `Text` which is a case in `XmlNode` DU:

```fs
type XmlNode =
    | ParentNode  of XmlElement * XmlNode list
    | VoidElement of XmlElement
    | Text        of string
```

So this sets the type for the whole list, `XmlNode`.

`br` function is defined as `let br = voidTag "br"` where `voidTag` function returns `VoidElement` which is another case in `XmlNode` DU, so it is fine.

And so I do not know what you wanted to say by `int model.Age`, and `int` is actually an [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.int%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) in F# to convert object to integer. Anyways, it does not return anything of type `XmlNode`. Instead, try

```
p [] [
    encodedText model.FirstName
    br []
    encodedText model.LastName
    br []
    encodedText (string model.Age)
]
```

Thereby you will `ToString` the age, it will turn to `Text` case of `XmlNode` and the code should compile.